# how to store php variable passed as id to javascript in a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to pass div `id` to javascript and print it out on console as  :

```
<?php echo 67;?>
```

The 67 is `id` here. I was wondering how can I store this value in my javascript variable `storeid` as `var storeid = 67`?

My code:

```
 echo "<h2 class='editme' id='<?php echo $id;?>' contentEditable='true'> Hello</h2>";

        echo "<script>

        $('h2.editme').click(function(){
            console.log(this.id);
            var storeid;

        });

        </script>";
```

Also, I want to use that `id` value to update the values in my sql. I can only test my code once I could somehow get the value of that id. How can I store the value of the `id` to javascript variable?

My code (This is to update sql once I get the id) - Not sure if it's right I can test it after getting `id` value:

```
 echo "<h2 class='editme' id='<?php echo $id;?>' contentEditable='true'> Hello</h2>";

            echo "<script>

            $('h2.editme').click(function(){
              var content2 = $(this).html();

                console.log(this.id);
                var storeid;//once I get the id
 $.ajax({
                      url: 'updateDescription(storeid, content2)',
                      success: function(respon) {
$('.editme').html(respon);
                      }
                    });

            });
   
            </script>";

function updateDescription($user_unique_id, $content2)
{
    try {
        require "testing.php";
        $sql = "UPDATE icecream  SET
             desc = :desc
             WHERE id = :id";
        $stmt->bindParam(':desc', $content2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $user_unique_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo 'Record updated';
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning JSON from a PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script)

Answer (score -1):

this way:

```
echo '<script>
   var storeid = '. $id .'
 </script>';
```

more readable way:

```
// somefile.php
<?php

   $id = 67;

?>

<h2 class='editme' id='<?php echo $id;?>' contentEditable='true'> Hello</h2>

<script>
  var storeid = <?php echo $id; ?>
  // rest of javascript code
</script>

<?php
 // rest of the php code
```

Comment: This does not print the value 67. It prints `<?php echo 67; ?>` which I am already printing.

Comment: @Haihv wait. is it literally printing: `<?php echo 67; ?>`?? that's impossible. is it processing your other code alright?